# outputting \r\n after text is decoded - PHP

Tags: php, encoding, str-replace, nl2br

I am building an application where users can enter a note into a textarea. The note is then encoded when entered into the database. When I decode the returned value, the nl2br function isn't working. It isn't replacing the \r\n with the br tag. When not encoding/decoding text, it works.

I am using the following code to encode/decode my information: http://www.myphpscripts.net/tutorial.php?id=9

If I enter into a textarea:

```
Hello  
World
```

It encodes it, and then returns when decoded

```
Hello\r\nWorld.
```

I can do a str_replace, but as I come to understand, depending on the browser, a textarea may use \n or \r instead of \r\n.

Not sure what a good solution is... please help! Thank you!

Comment: is there a need to encode the text when storing it in the database?

Comment: The code in that tutorial won't convert a newline to `"\r\n"`

Comment: ianbarker: the notes contain private data. For security purposes, it must.

Comment: @steeped If you're going to store the key in the database, you might just as well not encode it.

Comment: The encode/decode code in that script is absurd. Just use real encryption!

Comment: The type of newline doesn't depend on the browser you use, but on the OS. Windows uses \r\n, unix like systems use \n

Comment: Are you on a pre-5.4 release with magic quotes enabled?

Comment: @Tom van der Woerdt: it isn't.

Comment: @Francis Avila: this is the code I was recommended after doing some research into encoding/decoding. What would you recommend instead?

Comment: Use `crypt()` which is a standard PHP function. Also: what happens if you replace the `$_POST` line (which you probably have) with `"Hello\r\nworld"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the text you are converting is in a "<textarea>" do not use "<br />".

If you are converting text to be placed in a text area, use...

```
str_ireplace("\r\n", "\n", $db_string); //or something similar
```

If you are converting text to be placed OUTSIDE a text area, use...

```
str_ireplace(array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), '<br />', $db_string);
```

Separate browsers use whatever, but I believe they all can read just "\n".  However on a side note, the operating system determines "\r\n" vs "\n".  Just use "\n".  So replace "\r\n" with "\n".  Or just leave "\r\n", **use either, as long as you don't put br tags into your textarea tags you'll be all set.**

Mac = Linux = \n
Windows = \r\n

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your decoded string `Hello\r\nWorld.` in windows operating system using zend studio 7.2.0. I found nl2br() is working fine in both case `\r\n and \n`. You should double check your decoded string. May be you are doing addslashes() before encoding it.If so then you have to use stripslashes() before using nl2br().

Comment: stripslashes will just make Hello\r\nWorld become HellornWorld.

Comment: I am doing <?php $str = "Hello\r\nWorld";
echo nl2br($str);` and output is Hello<br />
World

Answer (score -1):

You can use `stripslashes($text)` to strip those. However, I'd recommend finding out why the slashes are added. Are you using `addslashes` ?

Comment: Not using addslashes. It's automatically adding \r\n when I hit the enter key and go to a new line within the textarea.

Comment: Yeah, but browsers will send them as actual \r\n characters instead of "\r\n". Something on the server's end is adding them, which could be `addslashes` or even "magic quotes".