# display user input without \n\r

Tags: php

I use functions (`check(removeTags($data))`) to save the text in `mysql` database:

```
function check($data){
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $data = stripslashes($data);
    }
    $data =addcslashes( mysql_real_escape_string($data) , "%_" );
    return $data;
}
function removeTags($data){
    $data=trim($data);  
    $data=strip_tags($data);
    return $data;
}
```

I use this function to display text above was saved to the user.

```
function output($data){
    return htmlspecialchars($data,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
}
```

But Unwanted character are added to the text.replace `newline('<br/>')` with `"\r\n"`.

I use `stripslashes` but it didn't worked ( replace `'\r\n'` with 'nr' ).

I use `str_replace("\r\n", "<br />",$data)` but it didn't worked too.

how can i remove `'\r\n'` ?

---

edit

see this [outputting \r\n after text is decoded - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337206/outputting-r-n-after-text-is-decoded-php) .

but user input is not encoded with that function ( like `encode` ),user input language is `persian` (Arabic).

Comment: I have never seen `\n\r`. Where does it come from? How did you find out it was indeed that sequence? Is it a literal string (4 characters) or are they LFCR (2 characters)=?

Comment: `"\n\r"` is a string with two newline characters. `'\n\r'` is a string of 4 characters afaik. Are you aware of the difference between the double quoted strings and the single quoted strings in php?

Comment: yes 
I know the difference between them.

Comment: This code is extremely strange. I've no idea what it's trying to do.

Comment: @navid - So you basically want to make the text in just one single line with no line breaks, correct?

Comment: What does *replace newline('<br/>') with "\n\r"* mean?

Comment: Where are these characters added? I am not aware of a function `newline()`, so you are probably defining it yourself.

Comment: @Magnus Burton - no i want use line break,

Comment: @navid - You want to replace *\n\r* with a *<br />*?

Comment: I hope you understand that `\n\r` is different to `\r\n`. `\r\n` is one line break. `\n\r` is two.

Comment: Simple: don't mangle your text. Read http://kunststube.net/escapism.

Comment: @navid It's still unintelligible. Is the $data string text or is it HTML? Could you give a sample string before and after the wanted transformation?

Comment: user enter this note in textarea :  سلام نوید  خوبی؟    but output is  سلام نوید\r\nخوبی؟

Comment: $data is a string text.

Comment: سلام نوید newline(enter space on keyboard) خوبی؟

Comment: If you want to turn the \n to <br/> you could use PHP's built-in function `nl2br()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 0):

For remove all new line characters from string use:

```
function check($data) {
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $data = stripslashes($data);
    }

    // this will remove all \n\r from output what you asked in question
    $data = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $data);

// in case you want new line in place of \n\r use line below
//  $data = nl2br($data); 

    $data = addcslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($data) , "%_");
    return $data;
}
...
```

Make sure you use this on clean user input. Before `addslashes` or other escaping methods. After escaping [EOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) characters became "\\r\\n" and `str_replace` will not work on them.

Comment: @navid You need use this before `addslashes` in `function check`. It'll work.

Comment: @navid Hmm.. Strange this should work if placed in right place. Just curious what will be right solution.

Comment: @AlexanderYancharuk Since you remove all `\r` and `\n` characters, there is no point in trying to replace combinations of them, as they will already be gone.

Comment: @navid So, was it helpful or you still have `\n\r` in output?